# How do I retrieve data and present it earliest in date order through PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, button

I want to get data from my database and present each field in separate divs - which I can do. However it is ordered earliest to latest meaning the first bits of data are at the top. How do I get it the other way round? Is it something I have to do in phpMyAdmin?

I am a Noob, please help. (thanks in advance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood is that you want to display the data in descending order. Use ORDER BY clause, which helps you to sort the data either in ascending or descending order.
for example:

SELECT * FROM shop
ORDER BY date DESC;

Comment: This is the exact same answer that was given 10 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual SQL statements and tables its hard to give a definitive answer.

However, you're looking for the [ORDER BY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by) clause. You can order something by a field in either Ascending (1, 2, 3) or Descending (3, 2, 1) Order.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY HireDate ASC
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY HireDate DESC
```

To get it in reverse order.